# Angular : ng-style not working with background image

Tags: angularjs

Without directive, that works and display kitten

```
    <section class="slide-show" style="background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/g/1000/175')">
        hello
    </section>
```

With ng-style, that fails :

```
<section class="slide-show" ng-style="{'background-image':url('http://placekitten.com/g/1000/175')}">
  hello
</section>
```

However using ng-style with background-color works :

```
<section class="slide-show" ng-style="{'background-color':'blue'}">
   hello
</section>
```

Is there a typo, or something I missed with Angular ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole value of `background-image` should be inside of a string when using `ng-style`.

Try this:

```
<section class="slide-show" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(http://placekitten.com/g/1000/175)'}">
  hello
</section>
```

It's also worth mentioning you don't need quotes for the background-image CSS property.

```
**Syntax**
background-image: none
background-image: url(http://www.example.com/images/bck.png)

background-image: inherit
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: While it works, I had in fact to use it with a method call in the ng-style. I switched to jQuery.css() method for this : at least I understand and I can debug the syntax I write. But I still love Angular :)